# Solid state physics. Reciprocal lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals

Why do we need to construct a primitive unit cell out of the direct unit cell to get the idea about the reciprocal lattice?

Why can't we get the same idea of the reciprocal lattice from the direct unit cell itself?

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_lattice):

> a reciprocal lattice is defined as the set of wavevectors
> $\mathbf {k}$ of plane waves in the Fourier
> series of any function $f(\mathbf {r} )$
> whose periodicity is compatible with that of an initial
> direct lattice in real space.

Therefore, the key information embodied in the reciprocal lattice is the periodicity of the direct lattice. Such periodicity is immediately available from the primitive unit cell (any choice of its basis vectors fully describe the translational symmetry), while it is not evident with conventional cells.